# SQL compare two columns for same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

With SQL Server 2012, I have two columns that I would like to compare. Both are on the same table, so no joins are needed.

Basically I need to compare two columns, for example `scan1` and `scan2` and if their value's match, then I need a `1`, else `0`. The results of the match would output to AS Results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like `SELECT .... , CASE WHEN scan1 = scan2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_equal FROM table1` should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

You can go like:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN Scan1 = Scan2 THEN 1 
       ELSE 0 END AS ColumnAlias
FROM YourTable
```