# Finding rows with different id but same date

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider below table table:

```
id    date
1     2016
1     2017
2     2017
2     2017
3     2016
3     2017
4     2018
5     2018
```

How can I get only rows with same date but different id .

Right now I can only get ids with more than 1 count like so:
Current Query is

```
"SELECT * FROM posts WHERE userid = :userid ORDER BY postdate DESC"
```

I want That ...

```
id    date
1     2016
3     2016
2     2016
1     2017
2     2017
3     2017
4     2018
5     2018
```

Comment: Please don't just ask us to solve the problem for you. Show us how you tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us exactly what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work. Give us a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: This is literally MySQL 101. Google has thousands of examples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL compare two columns for same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710825/sql-compare-two-columns-for-same-value)

Comment: yes i asked for solve my problem  if you can solve then ans

Comment: If you don't have a primary key, you don't really have a table

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SELECT statement with an INNER JOIN containing an inline view in which there exists `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id)>1` clause :

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.*
  FROM posts p1
  JOIN
  (
   SELECT date 
     FROM posts
    GROUP BY date
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT id)>1 ) p2
    ON p2.date = p1.date
```

<kbd>[Demo 1](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=26557b112e32e58c5b833627efb21ae4)</kbd>

Update : If you had DBMS version 8+, then you could use window analytic function as an alternative :

```
WITH posts2 AS
(
 SELECT p1.*, COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY date) AS CNT
   FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT * FROM posts ) p1
)
SELECT id, date
  FROM posts2
 WHERE CNT > 1;
```

<kbd>[Demo 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=584cb382a57637461cef2502fb62f143)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for that but have any simple idea like one line mysql code

Comment: you're welcome. What's your DBMS version? 8+ or not? @RomelKhan .

Comment: Im on localhost Xamp  Mysql is 5.7 reference manual

Comment: tell me how can i get these 8 version if you want to know me

Comment: I've added an alternative for version 8 @RomelKhan .